# How to redirect user to a new page/popup in a chrome extension in V3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have 2 html files in my chrome extension. One is login.html and the other is popup.html
When the user enters the correct credentials and press login button I would like to redirect user to the popup.html file.

I have found out this code for that operation and wrote this code in login.js

```
const loginBtn = document.getElementById("login");
loginBtn.onclick = function () {
   chrome.action.setPopup({
      popup: "popup.html",
   });
};
```

The above code works  when I switch the tabs and click on the extension again, i.e., it is not immediately happening.

I am looking for a functionality where as soon as a user clicks on the login button user must be immediately redirected to the other page.

Comment: Add `location.href = 'popup.html'`

Comment: Did you find out the solution to this bro?

Comment: I have actually tried whatever @wOxxOm suggested and it worked